# Hyperlink Error on Sharepoint 2013 List when clicked : "url field contains invalid data. please check the value and try again"

Tags: sharepoint-2010, hyperlink, sharepoint-2013

We have custom list with a column consisting URL hyperlink on SharePoint 2010 Now, we have upgraded to SharePoint 2013. When we click on the hyperlink, it throws error says **URL field contains invalid data, Please check the value and try again"** But it works like a charm in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re creating the hyperlink in 2013? Obviously if the list is very long changing each one to work properly woud not be the right solution, but the reason it may not work might have to do with changes made from custom list properties that were created in 2010. Now the conversion of the information is different when used on 2013.